# How to go to a certain pixel in ScrollView in Basic4android

Tags: scrollview, basic4android

I am currently making a comic app n for the pictures, i am usin a scrollview. Since there are many pictures, i want to create a Box where the picture's name is typed and it takes you to the picture in the contained activity.. How can i do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
```

or

```
sv.scrollTo(5, 10);
```

Comment: what does it mean **which activity** ??